# How to compare a string extracted from StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I wanna use the program to check the district, but something wrong I couldn't fix it.

ex: `abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno`

> jkl = true; 
>   abc = flase

```
public boolean isDistrict (String districtCheck){

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(address,",");
    int tokenno = st.countTokens();

    for(int i=0;i<tokenno-2;i++)
        st.nextToken();

    String district  = st.nextToken();
    if(st.nextToken()==district);
        return true
        else
        return flase
```

Comment: What is your question ? Also, have you even tried to compile it ? Because it doesn't, there are several distinct errors.

Comment: `String district  = st.nextToken();` what are you trying to compare in the next if statement?

Answer (score 1):

The Strings can not be compare with "==" instead use "equals()"

You code must be:

```
public boolean isDistrict (String districtCheck){

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(address,",");
    int tokenno = st.countTokens();

    for(int i=0;i<tokenno-2;i++)
        st.nextToken();

    String district  = st.nextToken();
    if(st.nextToken().equals(district))
        { return true; }
        else {
        return false; } }
```